# How to remove a List string element if it contains a string element from another List?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

### Setup

I have these three lists.

```
List<List<string>> tokens = new List<string>();
List<string> token = new List<string>();
List<string> sets = new List<string();
```

One complete `token` List that would be in the `tokens` List.

```
{"<card>"",
 "    <name>Domri Emblem</name>",
 "    <set picURL="http://magiccards.info/extras/token/Gatecrash/Domri-Rade-Emblem.jpg" picURLHq="" picURLSt="">GTC</set>",
 "    <color></color>",
 "    <manacost></manacost>",
 "    <type>Emblem</type>",
 "    <pt></pt>",
 "    <tablerow>0</tablerow>",
 "    <text></text>",
 "    <token>1</token>",
 "</card>"}
```

The `sets` list would look like this.

```
{"ARB", ..., "AVR", ..., "GTC", ..., "ZEN"}
```

I want to go through each `token` in `tokens` and remove each string in `token` that contains any of the elements in `set`.

### Example

The `tokens` list has a few `token` elements. One `token` (say token1) has an element like this.

```
{..., "    <set picURL="http://magiccards.info/extras/token/Gatecrash/Domri-Rade-Emblem.jpg" picURLHq="" picURLSt="">GTC</set>", ...}
```

Another `token` (say token2) has these two elements.

```
{..., "    <set picURL="http://magiccards.info/extras/token/magic-2012/pentavite.jpg" picURLHq="" picURLSt="">M12</set>",
"    <set picURL="http://magiccards.info/extras/token/player-rewards-2004/pentavite.jpg" picURLHq="" picURLSt="">MI</set>", ...}
```

Say the `sets` list was modified to contain only `{"ARB", "GTC", "M12"}`.

How would I go through each `token` in `tokens` and remove string elements that contain any of the string elements in `sets`? So, after that process, token1 will not have that element above and token2 will only have the second presented element?

### What I Have Tried

This goes through each `token` in `tokens` and removes any element in `token` that contains the string `"GTC"`.

```
foreach (var token in tokens)
{
    token.RemoveAll(str => str.Contains("GTC"));
}
```

I looked through some other questions and found this but it doesn't work.

```
foreach (var token in tokens)
{
    token.RemoveAll(sets.Contains);
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Side note - your sample looks like XML... Please consider using XML APIs instead if it is indeed XML.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I didn't know about any XML APIs but hindsight makes it seem obvious they would exist. Thanks, I will look into them.

Comment: Starting point - search for [C# XDocument](http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+XDocument) - there are plenty examples on MSDN and many question on this site.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov A brief search earlier pointed me to only loading an XML but those keywords gave me more. Particularly, getting information found between tags. In my case, anything between the `<set>` tags and other easier ways to extract more information from my XML file. I really should look for (and study) APIs before I try my unwieldy approaches. Thanks again, this time for the guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach (var token in tokens)
{
    token.RemoveAll(str => sets.Any(s => str.Contains(s)));
}
```

Comment: That works. Thank you. Will mark as answer at the end of the time limit.